# .htaccess speed vs. symlink or DNS setting I don't know about?

Tags: dns, symbolic-link, redirection, htaccess

This is probably a very simple question, but there's so much content out there that it was hard to google the correct problem I have.

I have 3 domains that I all want to go the very same place, including all subdomains, everything.  .net, .org. and .com

I want .org to be the master.

Currently i'm using symlinks, but I'm wondering if i could improve speed or anything other consequences I'm unaware.  I know I could use .htaccess files to redirect, or something in the DNS directly that would give me another options?

What are my options basically?

Using mediatemple gs in this scenario, if that matters at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to set the destination of a website is through your DNS settings in your website control panel because it re-directs at server level and so it does not have to load the symlink file. A .htaccess file would probably be the same speed as the symlink.